# How to call block from outside its declaration?

Tags: ios, swift, block

Hello I have following requirement.

I want to call completion block after the delegate method triggered.

Please find bellow sample snippet as example.

```
typealias CompletionBlock = (_ result: NSData?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void

 func Method1(block:CompletionBlock) 
{ 
   //SOME CODE
}

func Method2
{
    Completion(data,error)
}
```

---

`Method2` is my delegate method.
So when I call `Method1` from some other class it will enter into block once pointer is on `Method2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create one property like this,

```
var completionBlock : CompletionBlock!
```

Now on `Method1`

```
func Method1(block:CompletionBlock) { 
   self.completionBlock = block
}
```

on `Method2`

```
func Method2 {
    self.completionBlock(data,error)
}
```

I have not tested this code, but implemented like this in one of my application. Hope this may help you.